# Marshmallow: declare a complex schema

Tags: python, marshmallow

I'm struggling to declare this schema correctly. My main problem is that I dont know how to manage the ny, boston part considering its coming from a list of cities and can change at any time.How can I do?

It should look like:

```
 {
        
             "adresses": {
                 "ny": { "street":"jump", "number":"21", "postcode":"234"}
                "bos": { "street":"run", "number":"23", "postcode":"254"}
   }
}
```

Here's my code

```
        class AddressSchema(Schema):
                class Meta:
                    fields = ["street", "number", "postcode"]
            
        adresses = fields.List(fields.Nested(AddressSchema))
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the list of cities? E,g, is "ny" and "bos" an attribute of each address? What if there is more than one address per city? How should that be represented, or is that not possible?

Comment: Sorry maybe it's not clear enough, I changed a little the payload; Only one address per city, and this list would be taken from a db and would be different for every shop (just an example)